# can you filter what files show in a folder browser dialogue using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i am looking at building a pretty simple program that when you browse for a file it only populates the browser with files that have "W2ER" in the file name.

is this possible to do?

right now i have a pretty standard on button click that opens up the folder browser for code.

Comment: You moved to a new "commenting environment" :) You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Filter Property` can deliver what you want. Sample code for `OpenFileDialog1`:

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Files with W2ER in their name | *W2ER*.*"
```

NOTE: you can replace `.*` with the extension you want to restrict the search further. Now it looks for files of any type with "W2ER" in any part of their names. `*W2ER*.txt` would look just for TXT files with "W2ER" in their names.

Comment: @BSanders ?! what you mean with not working? You have to replace OpenFileDialog1 with your own OpenFileDialog1 object and should be fine. Feel free to show your code, such that I can be of further help.

Comment: so this is what i am trying and it's not really working

"Employer W2 Files | *ER_W2.mdoc"

the file name convention is company_year_er_w2.mdoc

Comment: @BSanders I have tested it and it works. Please show the whole code you are using.

Comment: COID and Year are dim'd strings above this section but here is my open file dialog code. 

ofd_Storeroom.InitialDirectory = "\\server\M3\Storeroom\" + COID + "\" + Year + "\"
                ofd_Storeroom.Filter = "Employer W2 Files | *ER_W2.mdoc"
                ofd_Storeroom.ShowDialog()

Comment: @BSanders This code should work. So you need to know what happens in your specific project. First thing is starting testing simple files (just to remove sources of errors): test a local directory, instead a network one. Other potential source of error is the remaining code in your app; start a new project, put an OpenFileDialog control on it (OpenFileDialog1 is its name by default) and write these two lines in the Form_Load method:         OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Employer W2 Files | *ER_W2.mdoc"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

Comment: when i try a new project it does work. you are correct. i'm not sure why it wouldn't workin my project though.

Comment: @BSanders As said, go step by step: firstly try with the network location and, if it works, put it into your original code (by doing an step-by-step execution). In this way you should be able to locate where the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the standard dialog then

```
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Some Suitable Name | *.W2ER"
```

[More details on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx)

Comment: You were some seconds quicker than me, but I think that this is not what the OP wants.

Comment: LOL. It is the answering-first stress, yours is more or less acceptable. Yesterday, I did a real ass... one.